# excel vba Evaluate() on string with IIF()

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

In excel VBA, my project has formula saved in a table. Through VBA, this formula is retireved into a `String` variable `tempFormula` the elements are are replaced with values from relevant source cells.

For Example if the formula stored is `(Actual/Total) * 100` and the terms `Actual`and `Total`are repalce with numberical values say `80` and `120`, the `tempFormula` would look like this `(80/120)* 100`.

On executing `Application.Evaluate(tempFormula)` gives the desird result, for this example it would be `66.67`.

I am facing error when the `String` variable `tempFormula` is develops into an expression after replacements to `"IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)"`. I mean to say that the VBA throws error when it reaches the statement

`tempResult = evaluate("IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)")`

I even tried

`tempResult = evaluate("IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)").Formula`

Can anyone help me out with a solution to this problem. I do not want to use a temporary cell elsewhere in the workbook to evaluate and use the result, Unless that's the only workaround to this issue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `IIF()` doesn't exist in Excel (it does in VBA) so using Evaluate on it and receiving an error makes sense. Can you give an actual example where you'd want to use something like this? (or use a normal IF function)

Comment: I have given the examples in the question. `Evaluate()` should be processing all valid excel formula. Correct? So `IIF()` is a valid formula/ function in excel. No?

Comment: Yes = Yes is hardly an example imo but w/e, you're also missing the double quotations around the yes, i.e. `IF(""Yes"" = ""Yes"", 20,0)` would work.

Comment: Like I said, `IIF()` isn't used in Excel, it's used in VBA when people want to go for one value or the other without going in a full `IF... Then... Else... End If` structure.

Comment: You didn't read my question properly sir, I said **when the String variable tempFormula is develops into an expression after replacements to "IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)".**. You missed the terms **after replacements**

Comment: It's very hard to understand what exactly you mean.. "after replacements" means you're not trying to evaluate what you have there? Because VBA throwing an error on `tempResult = evaluate("IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)")` makes sense, you can't evaluate that because evaluate takes Excel formula/reference, not VBA  exclusive functions. Why don't you just use a normal IF?

Comment: It's simple english @notus_panda. I am saying the formula is picked up from a stored cell position and the literals are Replaced to arrive at "True" = "True". After all such Replacements, `IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + IIf("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)` is stored in the string variable named `tempFormula`. Ok. If haven't still understood **Replaced*. I have used function `Replace()`to substitute the certain terms with "Yes". Hope you get it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255236/discussion-between-notus-panda-and-raky).

Comment: As @Notus_Panda has said, `IIF()` is **not** a valid Excel formula. Just use `IF()`

Comment: Not possible now. In office. Chat site are blocked. Can we do this after about 3-4 hours?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer instead so you don't need to wait 3-4 hours for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Evaluate, you can't use the IFF. Try it yourself:

```
tempResult = Evaluate("If("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0) + If("Yes" = "Yes", 20, 0)")
```

In VBA you could use:

```
Dim i
i = IIF("Test" = "Test", 20, 0) + IIF("TEST" = "TEST1", 0, 30)
Debug.Print i 'i would give 50 here
```

but IIF is not [a normal excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) formula so evaluate throws an error there.
My apologies for the confusion with the replacement part but I hope it's clear now to change the `IIF` to `IF` in this situation.

Comment: Got Old Man. What you said at First Instance, I did not catch. It was `IF()` that I need to Use and **NOT** `IIF()`. Thanks. @Notus_Panda